# Neo4j - find nodes by relationships criteria

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a simple graph in Neo4j graph-database:

[image: simple graph]

How to find nodes (using cypher) which:

1. have 3 relationships (result: node c, node e)?
2. have 2 outgoing relationships (result: node c, node e)?
3. have 1 incoming and 1 outgoing relationships only (result: node a, node b, node d, node d1)?

Comment: I have no idea unfortunately. Can you suggest me a direction for thinking? For example more examples of complex and very complex queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you started, but you should really read the manual, it's very detailed and easy to follow- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html

Also consider the online course- http://neo4j.com/graphacademy/online-course-getting-started/

1. Nodes that have 3 relationships:

   `MATCH (n)
   WHERE size((n)--())=3
   RETURN n`
2. Nodes that have 2 outgoing relationships:

   `MATCH (n)
   WHERE size((n)-->())=2
   RETURN n`
3. Nodes that have one outgoing and one incoming relationship

   `MATCH (n)
   WHERE size((n)-->())=1 AND size((n)<--())=1
   RETURN n`

You should use labels btw.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've read the manual and i found such functions as nodes(), length(), relationships(), but i ignored function **size()**. So i'll again read and reread the manual. And special thanks for links.